# dlopen fails in boost python module

Tags: python, boost, boost-python, dlopen

My objective is to create a python extension module with boost python. The problem is that when code in the shared library uses dlopen to access symbols within the *same* library, it fails (details below). It seems like the symbols within the module are not loaded into the symbol table of the python process

I have the following code in a shared library myTest.so

```
// File 1
extern "C" void target_func() {
    std::cout << "Works!" << std::endl;
}

// File 2
typedef void (*Func) ();
void run() {
    void *handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)
    Func *method = (Func *)dlsym(handle, "target_func");
    // check if method is NULL and fail
}
```

Its contained in a boost python module as shown -

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myTest) {
    def("run", run);
}
```

The above code fails when I import the python module and execute

```
import myTest
myTest.run()

undefined symbol: target_func
```

However there is *NO* problem when I link myTest.so with a main function that calls run as below

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    run();
}

Output: Works!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the interpreter will not load extensions in a way that will share symbols across extensions.  This can be modified by setting the `dlopen()` flags used by the interpreter via [`sys.setdlopenflags()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdlopenflags).  The documentation states:

> To share symbols across extension modules, call as `sys.setdlopenflags(dl.RTLD_NOW | dl.RTLD_GLOBAL)`.

---

Here is the interpreter loading the extension with default settings:

```python
>>> import myTest
>>> myTest.run()
/usr/bin/python: undefined symbol: target_func
```

And success occurs after modifying the interpreter's `dlopen()` flags:

```python
>>> import sys
>>> import dl
>>> sys.setdlopenflags(dl.RTLD_NOW | dl.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>>> import myTest
>>> myTest.run()
Works!
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me a ton of toe stubbing